# Python help(): What does straddling an argument with `*` mean?

Tags: python

I encountered the following in an online Python course:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
help(plt.hist)

hist(x, bins=None, range=None, density=None,
weights=None, cumulative=False, bottom=None,
histtype='bar', align='mid', orientation='vertical',
rwidth=None, log=False, color=None, label=None,
stacked=False, normed=None, hold=None, data=None,
**kwargs)

Plot a histogram.

Compute and draw the histogram of *x*. The return value
is a tuple (*n*, *bins*, *patches*) or ([*n0*, *n1*,
...], *bins*, [*patches0*, *patches1*,...]) if the input
contains multiple data.
```

There are plenty of webpages explaining an asterisk prefix,
but **Main question: Is straddling with asterisks just an
indication of bolding or italicizing the argument name?**

On a related note, I use to think of annotations straddling some code
as "adornment".  However, I haven't been able to clearly corroborate
this with web searches.  What little I found seems to indicate that
adornment refers to adding code to code in a more complicated ways
than simple straddling.  **Secondary question: What is the commonly
accepted definition of adornment?**

Comment: I guess it's italic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is markdown markup language. `*text*` is *text*, and `**bold**` is **bold**.

[This](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet) is a popular reference for how to use markdown. It doesn't produce any styling in the console, but it implies emphasis.

**Edit**: For your second question, a quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=adornment) revealed:

> a thing that adorns or decorates, an ornament.

So basically, just a decoration. You could consider a comment a sort of decoration in your code, I guess, although when talking about comments, I would just use their traditional name to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you!. Regarding "adornment", I mostly found the common meaning.  In the context of source coding, it seems to mean more than simply straddlng a snippet of source code with additional annotation/delimiters, but indications of its meaning are rare.  As an adapted term, maybe there just hasn't been a precise meaning that has been put forth.

Answer (score 2):

> Is straddling with asterisks just an indication of bolding or
>   italicizing the argument name?

Yes, it is. Using asterisk (`*`) to *surround* a word is a common convention for italicisation / emphasis. Including, at the time of writing, the StackOverflow text editor. This is not valid Python syntax.

The only part of the documentation extracted via `help` where asterisks *are* important is the function definition:

```
hist(..., **kwargs)
```

See [What does ** (double star/asterisk) and * (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters) for an explanation of what asterisks mean in this context.

"Adornment" as far as I'm aware is *not* a Python concept.

Comment: Thanks, jpp.  The use of asterisk for text emphasis was probably meant for something other than DataCamp's online coding window.  There, the asterisks are simply displayed as part of the text. As for adornment, I thought it was a general concept in the coding world.